# Node js, %1 is not a valid Win32 application, js-bson: failed to load c++ bson extension, windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb, winapi, mongojs

I did npm install and node app.js.

Then it shows that

> [Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application;
>   C:...\mongojs.....\bson.node] js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson
>   extension, using pure JS version.

I am not sure if this is only one error or two separate errors. Also, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common causes for this:

1. You are load a module with a corrupt executable file, or a file that is just not an executable.
2. You are attempting to load a 32 bit module into a 64 bit process or vice versa.

My guess is that latter is your problem. I suspect you have a bitness mismatch with one of your extensions. You've downloaded the 32 version, but need the 64 bit version, or vice versa.

You can use a PE explorer tool,  dumpbin, etc. to check the bitness of the relevant files.

Comment: I have download 64 bits node js. The bit version should match. I have tried to dumpbin. However, I didn't have Visual Studio downloaded. So, it's not working.

Comment: I think I answered the question that you asked.